# Grails Spring Security UI Registration Additional Fields

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to add additional fields in the user registration fields provided by the plugin. I believe overriding the RegisterController is the right approach to add more fields(correct me if I am wrong). I have created a new RegisterController.groovy from the the original file  with following content. At this point I have not added new field properties, just trying to mimic what the plugin does.

```
package myPackage

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.dao.NullSaltSource
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.CommandObject
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.MailStrategy
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.PropertiesStrategy
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.RegistrationCodeStrategy

class RegisterController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {

    static defaultAction = 'register'

    def saltSource
    MailStrategy uiMailStrategy
    RegistrationCodeStrategy uiRegistrationCodeStrategy
    PropertiesStrategy uiPropertiesStrategy

    def register(RegisterCommand registerCommand) {

        if (!request.post) {
            return [registerCommand: new RegisterCommand()]
        }

        if (registerCommand.hasErrors()) {
            return [registerCommand: registerCommand]
        }

        def user = uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.createUser(registerCommand)
        String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : registerCommand.username
        RegistrationCode registrationCode = uiRegistrationCodeStrategy.register(user, registerCommand.password, salt)

        if (registrationCode == null || registrationCode.hasErrors()) {
            // null means problem creating the user
            flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.miscError')
            return [registerCommand: registerCommand]
        }

        sendVerifyRegistrationMail registrationCode, user, registerCommand.email

        [emailSent: true, registerCommand: registerCommand]
    }

}

class RegisterCommand implements CommandObject {

    protected static Class<?> User
    protected static String usernamePropertyName

    String username
    String email
    String password
    String password2

    static constraints = {
        username validator: { value, command ->
            if (!value) {
                return
            }

            if (User.findWhere((usernamePropertyName): value)) {
                return 'registerCommand.username.unique'
            }
        }
        email email: true
        password validator: RegisterController.passwordValidator
        password2 nullable: true, validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I get an error

```
Cannot invoke method findWhere() on null object.
```

Any idea to solve this problem would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Do you want this extra fields to be persistent in db, in User domain class?

Comment: yes, that is the goal. I also need to figure out how to make the registration page adhere to the User domain class constraints.

Comment: Late to the party, do you remember how you got around this issue? I don't think the answer below is correct and there's way more than just the suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController` has this package-private method:

```
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    super.afterPropertiesSet()

    RegisterCommand.User = User
    RegisterCommand.usernamePropertyName = usernamePropertyName

    forgotPasswordEmailBody = conf.ui.forgotPassword.emailBody ?: ''
    registerEmailBody = conf.ui.register.emailBody ?: ''
    registerEmailFrom = conf.ui.register.emailFrom ?: ''
    registerEmailSubject = conf.ui.register.emailSubject ?: ''
    registerPostRegisterUrl = conf.ui.register.postRegisterUrl ?: ''
    registerPostResetUrl = conf.ui.register.postResetUrl ?: ''
    successHandlerDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl ?: '/'

    passwordMaxLength = conf.ui.password.maxLength instanceof Number ? conf.ui.password.maxLength : 64
    passwordMinLength = conf.ui.password.minLength instanceof Number ? conf.ui.password.minLength : 8
    passwordValidationRegex = conf.ui.password.validationRegex ?: '^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$'
}
```

where the value of `RegisterCommand.User` is being set. Do that also in your new RegistrationController.